# Json flow file transformation in Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am new to NiFi, I have a requirement where i need the below JSON in below output format. I just want to remove one part completely from the json. Is it possible in Nifi. If possible which processor should i use.

Input :

```json
{
  "eventId": "123456",
  "eventType": "Sample",
  "eventTime": "2021-04-20",
  "payload": {
    "product": [
      {
        "status": "Published",
        "level": "Test",
        "productType": "Test",
        "productClassification": "Test",
        "productName": "Test",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "chargeUnit": "USD",
        "recurringFrequency": "Test",
        "eligibility": {
          "eligibleAccountCriteria": {
            "isShared": false,
            "eligibleAccounts": [
              {
                "accountId": 12345,
                "accountName": "Test"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output :

```json
{
  "eventId": "123456",
  "eventType": "Sample",
  "eventTime": "2021-04-20",
  "payload": {
    "product": [
      {
        "status": "Published",
        "level": "Test",
        "productType": "Test",
        "productClassification": "Test",
        "productName": "Test",
        "minQuantity": 1,
        "chargeUnit": "USD",
        "recurringFrequency": "Test",
        "eligibility": {
          "eligibleAccountCriteria": {
            "isShared": false,
            "eligibleAccounts": []
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/) with spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "batters": {
        "batter": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit 1 :**

The below spec removes the objects in the array. In case of arrays index of the array needs to be tracked while traversing.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "product": {
          "*": {
            "eligibility": {
              "eligibleAccountCriteria": {
                "eligibleAccounts": {
                  "*": ""
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks..Jagadesh..It is working in nifi. But it's not working if "batter"  is an array.

Comment: I have added the sample format i am working with. Is it possible to get above output in NiFi.